# How to access this internal storage directory?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to access this internal storage folder: `/data/data/com.ceriosrey.chattrbox/app_imageDir`

This is how i saved into it:

```
val cw = ContextWrapper(context)
        val directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val mypath = File(directory, imageName + ".jpg")
```

This is my attempt at trying to get to it to fetch the images:

```
//loading image here
        val essentialsActivity = EssentialsActivity()
        val context = essentialsActivity.baseContext
        val directory = context.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val mypath = File(directory.absolutePath, chattRitem.itemImageFileName )
        Picasso.get().load(mypath).into(itemView.imageView_essentials_image)    }
```

So basically, I need to get the path so i can use it in the load parameter for load() in picasso. Please help.

this is an actual file inside that folder:

> /Users/myname/Documents/AndroidStudio/DeviceExplorer/Nexus_6P_API_P
>   [emulator-5554]/data/data/com.ceriosrey.chattrbox/app_imageDir/0f0e9b44-9833-4224-8343-8da203d782cf_bigstep.jpg.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed the context. That was my issue. Here is my new code:

```
//loading image here
            val context = itemView.context
            val path: String = context.filesDir.absolutePath
            val file = File(path, chattRItem.itemImageFileName )
            Picasso.get().load(file).into(itemView.imageView_people)
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is, path has `app_imageDir` but you are using `imageDir` so change it.

Note : extra `.jpg`, probably `chattRitem.itemImageFileName` already has `.jpg` extension so no need of it

Comment: i'll try this when I get to my comp. ty for the quick reply sir.